# Firmware copy when kernel updates

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I have a mythbuntu 12.04 install using a hauppage 2250 tuner card, with each kernel update I have to manually copy the tuner card firmware to the new /lib/firmware/3.8.0-xx-generic folder.  I have automatic updates turned off so I can see everything that is installed since this 'broke' my PVR the first time it happened.
Is there a way to automate the firmware copy when the kernel updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/move the firmware directly to `/lib/firmware` instead of the subfolder. That way it should be found for any kernel version and you won't need to automate the copying.

Answer (score 0):

There is a copy in /lib/firmware but the tuner only works when the firmware files are in the subolder, something I found while building this machine.

Comment: In response to -bseibold